# How to pass argument to action in UIGestureRecognizer initWithTarget action

Tags: selector, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using the code below

```m
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processTap)];

- (void) processTap
{
//do something
}
```

But I need to send a data to processTap function. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I think this should help you out:http://stackoverflow.com/a/5035335/177136

Answer (score 30):

**Example:**

```m
UIImageView *myPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-me-plese.png"]];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processTap:)];

[myPhoto setTag:1]; //set tag value
[myPhoto addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[myPhoto setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

- (void)processTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"tabbed!!");
    NSLog(@"%d", sender.view.tag);    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Always try to provide an explanation to your code.

Comment: If all you need is the `UIView` in which the gesture occurred in, then this is a poorly documented, yet valid answer. Otherwise, you must combine with this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594610/objective-c-storing-hidden-information-into-a-uiview from @nielsbot

Comment: This tagging is extremely useful for passing UserData - no need to do messy location calculations...

Answer (score 3):

There's a good answer to a similar question at [iOS - UITapGestureRecognizer - Selector with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960512/ios-uitapgesturerecognizer-selector-with-arguments), but if you want to pass data that you don't want to attach to the view, I recommend creating a second function that has access to the data you need. For example:

```m
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(passDataToProcessTap)];

- (void)passDataToProcessTap {
    [self processTapWithArgument:self.infoToPass];
    // Another option is to use a static variable,
    // Or if it's not dynamic data, you can just hard code it
}

- (void) processTapWithArgument:(id)argument {
    //do something
}
```